# How can I display a Shopify product item variant in seperate tags?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

Using the following displays the variant as one item.
Example. Size and colour display as `<li>small/red</li>`

```
{% unless item.product.has_only_default_variant %}
    <li>{{ item.variant.title }}</li>
{% endunless %}
```

I'd like to display

size: small

colour: red

Is this possible in Liquid/ shopify?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to retrieve variant's option name like "size" or "colour" from variant's object. Maybe you might try something different like this (not tested):

```
{% for option in product.options %}
  {% case forloop.index %}
    {% when 1 %}
    {% assign option_name1 = option.name %}
    {% when 2 %}
    {% assign option_name2 = option.name %}
    {% when 3 %}
    {% assign option_name3 = option.name %}
  {% endcase %}
{% endfor %}
```

And then:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {% if variant.option1 %}
    <p>{{ option_name1 }}: {{ variant.option1 }}</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% if variant.option2 %}
    <p>{{ option_name2 }}: {{ variant.option2 }}</p>
  {% endif %}
  {% if variant.option3 %}
    <p>{{ option_name3 }}: {{ variant.option3 }}</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```